# Python query runs but doesnt insert into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, sql-insert

I have bad a python script that connects to a db gets information and then uses a few variables to input this information back into the db. I have tweaked the code until it runs with no errors but in the end it doesnt actually insert anything into the db. Here is the insert code i am using

```
company_name = input("what is the company name?: ")
host=("")
ts = time.time()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Start DB connection
conn = mysql.connector.connect (user=dbUser,password=dbPassword,host=host,buffered=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Print Database Information
select_db = ("")
cursor.execute(select_db)
api_keys = ("select * from api_keys order by API_KEYS_ID desc limit 1")
cursor.execute(api_keys)
#print(api_keys)
#for (api_keys) in cursor:
#    print(api_keys[0])
#api_key_id = api_keys[0] + 1
#print(api_key_id)
api_keys_id = 170

##
add_api_key = ("INSERT INTO api_keys(api_keys_id, api_key, status, email, ip_address, filter_query, create_date, description) \
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",  (api_keys_id , api_token , 'A' , email , '*' , '(OwnerPartyID:' + ownerPartyID + ') AND (SalesStatus:' + salesStatus + ')' , timestamp , company_name + ' key'));

cursor.execute(*add_api_key)
conn.commit()
print(add_api_key)
```

Comment: you are probably not committing changes. conn.commit() should do it, conn being the name of your connection object

Comment: thanks for the answer but sadly that didnt do it either.

Comment: try with
cursor.execute('COMMIT')

Comment: that seems to have done it.